# Graph ops missing from the python registry

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to run the example code from [bertseq2seq/roberta24_bbc](https://tfhub.dev/google/bertseq2seq/roberta24_bbc/1):

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import sentencepiece

text_generator = hub.Module(
    'https://tfhub.dev/google/bertseq2seq/roberta24_bbc/1')
input_documents = ['This is text from the first document.',
                   'This is text from the second document.']
output_summaries = text_generator(input_documents)
print(output_summaries)
```

I created a virtual environment using Python v3.7.4, installed TFv1 as described on the website:

```
pip install "tensorflow>=1.15,<2.0"
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-hub
```

But when I execute I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: NotFoundError
Graph ops missing from the python registry ({'SentencepieceOp', 'SentencepieceDetokenizeOp', 'SentencepieceTokenizeOp'}) 
are also absent from the c++ registry.
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

**UPDATE:** my `requirements.txt`:

```
absl-py==0.10.0
astor==0.8.1
astunparse==1.6.3
cachetools==4.1.1
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
gast==0.2.2
google-auth==1.21.2
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.32.0
h5py==2.10.0
idna==2.10
importlib-metadata==1.7.0
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
Markdown==3.2.2
mock==4.0.2
numpy==1.18.5
oauthlib==3.1.0
opt-einsum==3.3.0
protobuf==3.13.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
requests==2.24.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.6
scipy==1.4.1
sentencepiece==0.1.92
six==1.15.0
tensorboard==1.15.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.7.0
tensorflow==1.15.3
tensorflow-estimator==1.15.1
tensorflow-hub==0.9.0
tensorflow-text==1.15.1
termcolor==1.1.0
tf-sentencepiece==0.1.92
urllib3==1.25.10
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wrapt==1.12.1
zipp==3.1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem as you, but got it working in Tensorflow 2.6.0 and Python 3.9.1. The solutions below work on both CPU and GPU.

#### With a modified TF1 example

The following steps made the TensorFlow Hub example work:

- `pip install tensorflow-text`
- Add `import tensorflow_text as text` to the Python imports
- Disable eager execution: `tf.disable_eager_execution()`
- Use a TF1 session to get the result, including initializing variables and tables manually.

The full program looks like this:

```py
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_text as text

tf.disable_eager_execution()

text_generator = hub.Module('https://tfhub.dev/google/bertseq2seq/roberta24_bbc/1')
input_documents = ['This is text from the first document.',
                   'This is text from the second document.']
output_documents = text_generator(input_documents)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    final_output = sess.run(output_documents)

print(final_output)
```

#### With KerasLayer (TF2)

Even though the documentation doesn't mention it, it actually seems to work with the `KerasLayer` used for TF2 models. If you can accept getting *a lot* of warnings in the console, this should do it:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_text as text

text_generator = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/google/bertseq2seq/roberta24_bbc/1')
input_documents = tf.constant(['This is text from the first document.',
                               'This is text from the second document.'])
output_documents = text_generator(input_documents)

print(output_documents)
```

Note that the documents need to be wrapped in `tf.constant` to work in this case.

**Note**: You need a longer document text to get a meaningful summary. The two examples (e.g. "This is text from the first document") are not summarized.

Answer (score 0):

`Sentencepiece` ops have been moved to a separate package [`tf_sentencepiece`](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece/tree/master/tensorflow):

```
pip install tf_sentencepiece
```

You might also have to manually import it at the start of your script if it doesn't work outright.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply but it did not work... same error. even after `import sentencepiece`.

Comment: added my full requirements list to original post